# Using .html() to replace replace element, is there a way to keep events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using `.html()` to replace jQuery element's inner html. As far as I can tell the original element that was inside the parent element that html is being used on is removed. If you maintain a javascript reference to that original element, you can reinsert it later, but with its events missing.

Is there a way to do a replacement via detaching `.detach()` the original element so that it still retains its events instead of removing it?

Comment: Do you have a code example of this?

Comment: Yes, you can use `.detach()`: http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: @Felix Kling The question is how to get .html() to use detach

Comment: You can't. Using `.html()` is the same as overwriting the content of an element with `innerHTML`. But there should be no problem to detach the elements first and then set the new content.

Answer (score 3):

you should use live to bind the events permanently, event to elements that enter the DOM after the binding. example:

```
$('.element').live('click', function(){
   ....
});
```

or if you're using jQuery 1.7+

```
$('.element').on('click', function(){
    ....
});
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery 1.4+ you can use the .detach() method.

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

var x = $('.element').detach();

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Ben Alman's jQuery replaceText plugin will allow you to replace the text and if you check his website (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/), it specifically has the following mentioned:

> So, why not just set .html( new_text ) ?
>   While using the jQuery .html() method is one of the fastest ways to replace text in a huge HTML structure, when you do this, all event handlers and references bound to any child elements are lost. This is not good!
>
> Now, if you have no event handlers or references to these elements, just update the .html() using a standard string replace, and everything will be super-fast! But if you do have event handlers and element references, you will need something a little “smarter” .. like this plugin.